# How to insert 5 rows using 1 insert stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 using c#.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have to save 5 files paths in single table with single time stored procedure call using Asp.net and backend is SQL Server 2008.

If it is with table-valued parameter, you're most welcome.

Please respond me as early as possible

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FileTest 
(
     ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
     FileName VARCHAR(255), 
     DateInserted DATETIME2(3)
)
```

Then you need to create a **table type** that can serve as the table-valued parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE FileNameType AS TABLE (FileName VARCHAR(255));
```

Next, you need to define a stored procedure that takes this table type as its parameter and inserts the data from the TVP into the table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertFileNames
    @TVP FileNameType READONLY
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO FileTest(FileName, DateInserted)
       SELECT FileName, Sysdatetime()
       FROM  @TVP;
```

Now, in your C# code, you need to have something like this:

```
// define some strings we need - connection string, name of stored procedure, name of the table type
string connectionString = "server=.;Database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
string storedProcedureName = "dbo.InsertFileNames";
string tvpValueTypeName = "FileNameType";

// set up data to insert - create a DataTable that has the same structure as your TVP type in SQL Server
DataTable filesNamesToAdd = new DataTable();
filesNamesToAdd.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FileName", typeof (string)));

// insert some rows into that DataTable
DataRow row = filesNamesToAdd.NewRow();
row["FileName"] = "C:\\autoexec.cmd";
filesNamesToAdd.Rows.Add(row);

row = filesNamesToAdd.NewRow();
row["FileName"] = "C:\\Windows\\Explorer.exe";
filesNamesToAdd.Rows.Add(row);

row = filesNamesToAdd.NewRow();
row["FileName"] = "C:\\Windows\\starter.xml";
filesNamesToAdd.Rows.Add(row);

row = filesNamesToAdd.NewRow();
row["FileName"] = "C:\\Windows\\WindowsUpdate.log";
filesNamesToAdd.Rows.Add(row);

row = filesNamesToAdd.NewRow();
row["FileName"] = "C:\\Windows\\mip.bin";
filesNamesToAdd.Rows.Add(row);

// set up SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using blocks
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn))
{
    // define the SqlCommand to be a stored procedure we're calling
    insertCommand.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // define the table-valued parameter; it's of type SqlDbType.Structured, and you need to tell it the TVP type in SQL Server
    SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TVP", SqlDbType.Structured);
    tvpParam.TypeName = tvpValueTypeName;
    tvpParam.Value = filesNamesToAdd;

    // open connection, call the stored procedure to insert data, close connection 
    conn.Open();
    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Done!